# is Kafka stream KTable commit interval based on Wall-clock-time?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I could not find any indication about the time used for the commit interval on KTable. Is it Walk-Clock-Time or Stream Time , Producer Time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to `commit.interval.ms` config, than the answer is wall-clock time.

Comment: Thx yes that is what I was referring to

Comment: Just a quick follow up on that. If the commit is wall-clock as you said, and the default of kafka stream, is stream time (default timestamp extractor), can't that cause a problem, in term of when to commit things ? Or is it that the fact that the commit is wall-clock it simply ignore the timestamp of the record, to decide when to commit ?

Comment: Record timestamps are ignored.

Comment: Thank you for the info